# Hazelcast Java - Predicates.and disregarding predicates other than first

Tags: java, hazelcast

I have an `IMap` with a class as key. This key have two attributes:

```
 static class MapKey implements Serializable{
        String uid;
        String service;

        public MapKey() {
        }

        public MapKey(String uid, String service) {
            this.uid = uid;
            this.service = service;
        }

        public String getUid() {
            return uid;
        }

        ...
    }
```

I'm initialising the map with just two simple values:

```
HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
final IMap<MapKey, String> map = hz.getMap("testmap");
map.addIndex("__key#uid", false);
map.put(new MapKey("uid1","service1"),"value1");
map.put(new MapKey("uid1","service2"),"value2");
```

Then I'm building a predicate with ands:

```
    static Predicate<MapKey, String> buildPredicate(MapKey key){
        final EntryObject entryObject = new PredicateBuilder().getEntryObject().key();
        final List<Predicate<MapKey, String>> predicateList = new ArrayList<>();
        predicateList.add(entryObject.get("uid").equal(key.getUid()));
        predicateList.add(entryObject.get("service").equal(key.getService()));

        final com.hazelcast.query.Predicate predicate = Predicates.and(predicateList.toArray(new Predicate[predicateList.size()]));
        return predicate;
    }
```

When I use this predicate it returns me the keys only filtered by uid, meaning, Collection values have a size of 2 instead of expected one.

```
Predicate<MapKey, String> predicate = buildPredicate(new MapKey("uid1","service1"));
Collection<MapKey> values = map.keySet(predicate);
```

Can anyone explain me this behaviour? What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you operate on `entryObject` is if it would be an immutable object, however it's not immutable. It's actually a builder and the operation `entryObject.get("uid").equal(key.getUid())` changes its state and records the predicate conditions. That is why if effect you execute `Predicates.and()` on two exactly equal Predicates.

Try the following, it will do what you try to achieve.

```
   static Predicate<MapKey, String> buildPredicate(MapKey key){
        final List<Predicate<MapKey, String>> predicateList = new ArrayList<>();
        predicateList.add(new PredicateBuilder().getEntryObject().key().get("uid").equal(key.getUid()));
        predicateList.add(new PredicateBuilder().getEntryObject().key().get("service").equal(key.getService()));

        final com.hazelcast.query.Predicate predicate = Predicates.and(predicateList.toArray(new Predicate[predicateList.size()]));
        return predicate;
    }
```